# VueJS/NodeJS environment variable changes not picked up by VS2022

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2022

I have a multi-part project with a couple of .net applications and a VueJS application. I have Visual Studio 2022 configured to launch two .net applications (APIs) and the VueJS application to debug.

Everything else seems to work as expected.

The crux of the issue is that the debug build through VS is not picking up changes to .env file (.env.local) - there is currently no other .env file in this project.

I'm doing a simple `console.log(process.env)` to check the values.

The file itself appears changed in VS, and if I do an `npm run serve` in PowerShell the console shows the expected values. However, when run with the VS2022 debugger it shows the original values that were present when I pulled down the project.

Given that the changes to the .env file are showing up when running directly, but not when debugging in VS, I'm thinking that the environment variables are somehow getting cached in VS? But I haven't the slightest where or how.

I've tried:

- cleaning the build (not sure what it does in this context?)
- exiting and relaunching VS
- building in PowerShell then coming back to VS

**Partial Solution**

Restarting my machine caused VS to finally pick up on the env variable changes. It's not ideal, but if someone needs a temporary solution in a pinch...